# Is there a way to enable/disable Haptic Feedback based on User approval?

Tags: flutter, dart, haptic-feedback

My idea is to implement haptic feedback on navigationitems but then I've realised that I have haptics set to off on most of my apps(battery saving reasons) So I was wondering if there is a way to prompt/override system settings rules in android with the flutter framework. E.g. with a toggle like you have for Light/Dark mode

Comment: When you say yuou have it set to off, do you just mean that you don't have the permission for vibrating enabled? Easy solution is just to store the user's preference either locally or in your userdb and then check on that value prior to triggering an haptic feedback.

Comment: Thanks Jet, i'll take a look into that. I will re-word that. My haptics on my samsung are disabled globally, I think my keyboard is the only thing that overrides that setting .